# HyperLedger Fabric SDK Go showing cannot convert nil to type csr.KeyRequest

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

One of the go-lang based microservice code require to connect with fabric's chain code, It was working fine until last time, no issue so far.

But now it's showing the following issue while building the go based microservice which have fabric client code to connect with fabric chaincode.

## ../vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util

../../vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:47:8: **cannot convert nil to type csr.KeyRequest**
../../vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:132:37: cannot use req.KeyRequest (type *csr.KeyRequest) as type csr.KeyRequest in argument to getBCCSPKeyOpts

Maybe its a dependency issue, I cleaned up the complete vendor directory and and done dep ensure --update ,but it showing same issue,

Further information :

Go Version 1.12

On GoPkg.Toml

[[override]]
   name = "github.com/hyperledger/fabric"
    branch = "master"

[[override]]
   name = "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go"
   branch = "master"

I have tried various combination and different branches of fabric-sdk-go, its still showing the same, though it worked fine earlier.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that there have been many changes on the packages which fabric-sdk-go depends on, since the release of 1.0.0-alpha5.

When I run go build now with just one importing of external dependency(github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go), I got the following go.mod file, (I use `go mod` for package management)

```
...

require (
    github.com/cloudflare/cfssl v0.0.0-20190726000631-633726f6bcb7 // indirect
    github.com/go-kit/kit v0.9.0 // indirect
    github.com/golang/mock v1.3.1 // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.2 // indirect
    github.com/google/certificate-transparency-go v1.0.21 // indirect
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-lib-go v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go v1.0.0-alpha5
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.1 // indirect
    github.com/prometheus/client_golang v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/viper v1.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/zmap/zlint v0.0.0-20190730215301-9971d62266e7 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20190724013045-ca1201d0de80 // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.22.1 // indirect
)
```

which contains packages of cutting-edge version and seems to make some build problems like below, including what you had.

```
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations
../../Go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@v1.0.0-alpha5/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations/system.go:185:43: undefined: "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus".Handler
../../Go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@v1.0.0-alpha5/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations/system.go:227:23: not enough arguments in call to s.statsd.SendLoop
        have (<-chan time.Time, string, string)
        want (context.Context, <-chan time.Time, string, string)
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util
../../Go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@v1.0.0-alpha5/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:46:8: cannot convert nil to type csr.KeyRequest
../../Go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@v1.0.0-alpha5/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:131:37: cannot use req.KeyRequest (type *csr.KeyRequest) as type csr.KeyRequest in argument to getBCCSPKeyOpts
```

I wrote go.mod file manually to contain specific versions of dependencies when I succeeded the build last time.

```
...
require (
    github.com/cloudflare/cfssl v0.0.0-20190409034051-768cd563887f // indirect
    github.com/go-kit/kit v0.8.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-logfmt/logfmt v0.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/golang/mock v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/google/certificate-transparency-go v1.0.21 // indirect
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-lib-go v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go v1.0.0-alpha5
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.1 // indirect
    github.com/prometheus/client_golang v0.9.2 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/viper v1.3.2 // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.20.1 // indirect
)
```

and it works well.

Comment: Thank you so much for further information like specific version to use for various dependencies of it, I will apply those on my stuff and then update here like how that goes.

Comment: I tried, Sure cfssl issue gone, but this still issue still coming : 
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@v1.0.0-alpha5/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations/system.go:185:43: undefined: "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus".Handler
make[1]: *** [build-only] Error 2 on doing go get this disappears : github.com/prometheus/client_golang

Answer (score 4):

I have found the root cause of that issue, Its like frequent incremental fixes/development on fab-sdk-go, and I defined the master version of fab-sdk-go on my code, and that to be fetched from Gopkg.toml file.

It took me like manually apply various versions of fab-sdk-go by dates, to figure out which is the best fab-sdk-go version, means that version which won’t give any compilation issue like above.

And when applied following version:

FAB-SDK-Go [FABG-815] make multi-errors on a single line: 56ebf9adac580e7e3251685fe4fe6e793df838dc , https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/commit/56ebf9adac580e7e3251685fe4fe6e793df838dc

It didn't give any error and it worked out.

Even I applied for releases like alpha1,alpha2,aplha3 as well for fab-sdk-go, but again those gave compilation issues.

**EDIT**

This issue came again, done the following to fix this :

➜  **apis git:(master)** ✗ go get github.com/cloudflare/cfssl@1.3.3
go: downloading github.com/cloudflare/cfssl v0.0.0-20190409034051-768cd563887f

go get: downgraded github.com/cloudflare/cfssl v1.4.1 => v0.0.0-20190409034051-768cd563887f

go get: downgraded github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go v1.0.0 => v1.0.0-beta2

➜  **apis git:(master)** ✗ go mod tidy
go: downloading github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go v1.0.0-beta2

➜  **apis git:(master)** ✗  go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@master

go: downloading github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go v1.0.1-0.20210201220314-86344dc25e5d

go get: upgraded github.com/cloudflare/cfssl v0.0.0-20190409034051-768cd563887f => v1.4.1

go get: upgraded github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go v1.0.0-beta2 => v1.0.1-0.20210201220314-86344dc25e5d

Comment: I tried to `go get -v github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@56ebf9adac580e7e3251685fe4fe6e793df838dc` but I still have the same compilation issues :/

Comment: I actually Cloned the Fabrick-SDK-Go on my gopath, and then again did the git checkout 56ebf9adac580e7e3251685fe4fe6e793df838dc for this specific version, and deleted Fabric-SDK-Go from my vendor directory, so that 56ebf9adac580e7e3251685fe4fe6e793df838dc version can be picked and it worked. Please check other revisions too from here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/commits/master

Answer (score 1):

#### Clean environment

Clean go.mod all require

#### Download the latest version

```sh
 go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@master
```

#### Download dependency

```sh
go mod tidy
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the issue is a breaking change in verson 1.3.4 of `github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/csr`.

Simply install 1.3.3 with the command below and the latest version of `fabric-sdk-go` works without any issues.

```
go get github.com/cloudflare/cfssl@1.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

since KeyRequest does not have an instance, it can not be converted to nil. You only have the variable kr that holds the values of the KeyRequest structure, which are string A and int S. You can try editing the csp.go like "if kr.A == "" && (kr.S != 2048 || kr.S != 3072 || kr.S != 4096)" in the line 48.